# addition is not working in my shell script

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash


# This is a comment
clear
echo "----------------------------------------"
read -p "please enter the first number" a
read -p "please enter the second number" b

sum = $(($a + $b))
sub = $(($a - $b))

echo "$a + $b = $sum"
echo "$a -$b = $sub"
echo "------------------------------------------"
```

This is my shell script(test3.sh), 
When i run by using

```
bash test3.sh
```

I am getting the following error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDldZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the syntax issues in variable assignment which should have been

```
sum=$(($a + $b))
sub=$(($a - $b))
```

Since you haven't specified that, `bash` tried to execute the `sum` as an executable with `=` and `$(($a + $b))` as its arguments.

Also you could get rid of the `$` symbol inside the arithmetic evaluation context and just do

```
sum=$((a + b))
sub=$((a - b))
```

Always use http://www.shellcheck.net to fix the syntax issues from the script.

Comment: yea I tried. It is saying to wait for 10 minutes

Comment: Thanks :). I am new to stack overflow. so I am not familiar.